# выборка с одной таблицы дважды, но с разными ИД

Tags: sql, sql-server

В MS Azure создана БД и подключена к MS Access. Пытаюсь сделать запрос который выберет ID Звонка, ФИО абонента1, ФИО абонента1.[image]

В таблице dbo_calls идет перечень звонков с ID абонентов, а в таблице dbo_Caller информация про абонентов[image: dbo_calls][image: dbo_caller]

Пытался сделать так:

```
SELECT dbo_calls.Id, dbo_calls.Caller1Id, dbo_Caller.FullName, dbo_calls.Caller1Id, dbo_Caller.FullName
FROM dbo_Caller INNER JOIN dbo_calls ON (dbo_Caller.Id = dbo_calls.Caller2Id) AND (dbo_Caller.Id = dbo_calls.Caller1Id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Секс по телефону? Тогда надо было связать звонки с двумя "копиями" таблицы участников секса.

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo_Calls calls
  JOIN dbo_Caller caller ON caller.Id = calls.Caller1Id
  JOIN dbo_Caller called ON called.Id = calls.Caller2Id
```

Предполагается, что вызывающая сторона - это caller1, а вызываемая caller2.

Comment: А зачем дублировать информацию, если абоненты одинаковы

Comment: Что, где дублируется?

Comment: >  связать звонки с **двумя копиями** таблицы участников и еще вопрос почему этот запрос не работает в ms access. В azure работает норм

Comment: Это воображаемая копия. Одна и та же таблица может быть хоть 100500 раз принимать участие в одном запросе. Каждое такое участие независимо одно от другого. Можно даже связи между ними устанавливать, как с другими таблицами: `caller.id = called.id` - кто звонил сам себе? Можно представить, что это "копии на время запроса". Изучайте матчасть. Это азы sql.