# SQLite3 "двойной" JOIN

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, join

Как правильно составить **JOIN** в **SQLite3** в следующей ситуации:

Есть таблица имён:

```
table "names"

"name_id" - integer primary key autoincrement
"name" - text
```

Есть таблица связей:

```
table "links"

"link_id" - integer primary key autoincrement
"name_a" - integer
"name_b" - integer
```

**name_a** и **name_b** - содержит **"name_id"** из таблицы **"names"**

Нужно получить **link_id**, **name_a** (с подменой), **name_b** (с подменой)

Если нужна одна подмена всё выходит без проблем, но когда более одной подмены из одной же таблицы - не получается, чего то я не знаю видимо на данный момент

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [выборка с одной таблицы дважды, но с разными ИД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526031/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%98%d0%94)

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно чего Вы хотите добиться и в чем заключается проблема. Приведите пожалуйста Ваш вариант запроса. Чем он Вас не устраивает? Какую ошибку дает при попытке выполнить? На данный момент слишком большой простор для фантазии, что у Вас могло пойти не так.

Comment: @reshu, select link_id, name, name from links join names on links.name_a=names.name, links.name_b=names.name (это конечно нерабочий запрос)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select links.link_id, a.name, b.name from links
join names a on links.name_a = a.name_id
join names b on links.name_b = b.name_id
```

Отличие от Вашего варианта заключается в том, что я при каждом использовании таблицы names даю ей разные псевдонимы (a и b). И в том, что второй раз таблицу подключаю не через запятую, а тем же самым join.

В реальности я и таблице links дал бы псевдоним l, чтобы не писать полное имя, но в Вашем случае оно не длинное и я уж не стал умножать сущности.